# kubectl get deploy deploymentname -o yaml equivalent in Fabric8 client

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

I've an existing deployment in my Kubernetes cluster. I want to read its deployment.yaml file from Kubernetes environment using fabric8 client.Functionality similar to this command - kubectl get deploy deploymentname -o yaml.
Please help me to get its fabric8 Java client equivalent.

Objective : I want to get deployment.yaml for a resource and save it with me , perform some experiments in the Kubernetes environment and after the experiments done,I want to revert back to previous deployment. So I need to have deployment.yaml handy to roll back the operation.
Please help.

Thanks,
Sapna

Comment: What have you tried with?

Comment: Have you checked out existing examples in fabric8 repository: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/kubectl/equivalents/LoadAndCreateDeployment.java

Comment: This example reads yaml file and creates Deployment. I need its opposite functionality. I've an existing deployment in Kubernetes cluster. I want to get its deployment.yaml file from cluster using Fabric8 client. Just like this command: kubectl get deploy deploymentname -o yaml

Comment: So far I am able to get Deployment Object using Fabric8 client as below:Deployment deploy = client.apps().deployments().inNamespace("abc").withName("ms1").get();            How can I get its corresponding yaml file (deployment.yaml) ? Please help.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the yaml representation of an object with the [Serialization#asYaml](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client-api/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/utils/Serialization.java#L140) method.

For example:

```
System.out.println(Serialization.asYaml(client.apps().deployments().inNamespace("abc").withName("ms1").get()));
```